# awk: Perform arithmetic on subset of columns and print all columns with modified values

Tags: awk

I have columns containing some values e.g.:

```
A 10 20 30 AA AAA AAAA
B 40 50 60 BB BBB BBBB
C 70 80 90 CC CCC CCCC
```

I want to perform an arithmetic operation like multiplication on cols 2,3,4 and return a new table.

```
A 100 200 300 AA AAA AAAA
B 400 500 600 BB BBB BBBB
C 700 800 900 CC CCC CCCC
```

I can operate specifically on cols 2,3,4 using

```
awk '{print $2*10"\s"$3*10"\s"$4*10}' inp > out
```

but dont know how to print the entire table with cols with modified values. Is there a way to do this in awk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example you calculate and print together. With `awk` you can do any modifications first on the fields and print finally all the line or a part of it like this:

```
awk '{$2=10*$2; $3=10*$3; $4=10*$4} {print}' file
```

`{print}` with no arguments means `{print $0}`, print the whole line. Also it can be replaced by any true condition, like `1`, for example `awk '1' file` means print every line.

So your command can be also:

```
awk '{$2=10*$2; $3=10*$3; $4=10*$4} 1' file
```

Additionally, before any body with actions (`{}`) we can have conditions. For example if we want to skip the first 5 lines, that condition is `NR>5` where NR is the record (usually means row) number. So here we do not consider the 5 first lines for the calculation but we print them together with all lines:

```
awk 'NR>5 {$2=10*$2; $3=10*$3; $4=10*$4} {print}' file
```

Here we totally ignore 5 first lines, we don't print them too:

```
awk 'NR>5 {$2=10*$2; $3=10*$3; $4=10*$4; print}' file
```

Comment: taking that logic a little bit forward, would it be possible to skip lines? So lets say in my example, the first 5 lines are NaNs and I dont want to consider them during the operation, but in the end I do want to include the NaNs in the final output.

Answer (score 2):

Adding a generic solution here, written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`. Just mention all field numbers in `fields` variable of `awk` with comma separated and mention digit by which you want to multiply fields in `multiplyBy` and that should do the trick.

```
awk -v multplyBy="10" -v fields="2,3,4" '
BEGIN{
  num=split(fields,arr,",")
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){
    look[arr[i]]
  }
}
{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    if(i in look){
      $i=($i * multplyBy)
    }
  }
}
1'  Input_file
```

***NOTE:*** Just now saw user's comments in other answer. In case some one wants to skip first 5 lines then change `{` before for loop to `FNR>5{` and that should do the trick for it.

Comment: Just now saw user's comments in other answer. In case some one wants to skip first 5 lines then change `{` before `for` loop to `FNR>5{` and that should do the trick for it.